# How to get those hotelid which are not having any entry after the date of particular product name?

Tags: sql-server

For an example:
I have a table t1 like:

```
ID   Name       Date        Product
1      A          20170101   AT
2      B         20170101    BT
1      A         20160102   A
2      B         20170106    D
3     C         20190101     F
3     C         20190101    GT
3     C         20190102    D
```

Now I want to get those hotel list which is not having any entry after the date of  (AT,BT,GT) product.

From Above table:
I need hotelname A result because if we see 3rd entry on table for name A it is on the 20160102 which is less than the date of (A-T) product, it means there is no entry after that.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to first retrieve all records with `-` in the product since this seems to be your criteria here, right? Then you could left join the result to the original table and by this evaluate the mentioned rule concerning the date. Following an example:

```
CREATE TABLE t (
        [ID]         INT          NULL,
        [Name] VARCHAR (80) NULL,
        [Date]   INT          NULL,
        [Product]    VARCHAR (80) NULL
    );

INSERT INTO t VALUES
 (1, 'A', 20170101, 'A-T')
,(2, 'B', 20170101, 'B-T')
,(1, 'A', 20160102, 'A')
,(2, 'B', 20170106, 'D')
,(3, 'C', 20190101, 'F')
,(3, 'C', 20190101, 'G-T')
,(3, 'C', 20190102, 'D');


WITH cte AS(
SELECT *
      ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Name] ORDER BY [Date]) rn
      ,COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY [Name]) cn
  FROM t
)
SELECT [Name]
  FROM cte
  WHERE Product IN (N'AT', N'BT', N'GT')
    AND rn = cn
```

see SQL fiddle for details: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/dde24/12/1

Comment: it could be any string not necessary (A-T) I have edited the column.

Comment: It is still providing some hotels which is having entry after that...

Comment: I modified my answer. The result in this example (using your example data) is "A" as described by you. The query checks if the product provided in the query is the last product for each name.
Which records are being displayed which you didn't expect to be displayed? Please provide further example data.

Comment: Thanks but you are late I already did this by row_number.I was thinking about your previous method.

Comment: at least in Fiddle my previous version displayed the same expected result ;-)